# basic Crystal Reports formula needed

Tags: crystal-reports-xi

HI I need a formula like this.

If table.col = 'PWB' or 'PDB' 'PBB'

display that value on the report

else

do nothing.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
IF {reportfield} IN ["PWB", "PDB", "PBB"] then {reportfield} else ""
```

In the format editor Display string X2.